# How to know the last position of a loop?

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following sql in a procedure:

```
    READ_LOOP: LOOP
    FETCH CUR INTO xStatus;
IF done THEN LEAVE READ_LOOP;
END IF;
    set i = i+1;        
    if i mod 3 = 0 then        
        SET DescrStatus = CONCAT(DescrStatus, xStatus, ' | ', CHAR(13));
    else if i = 1 then
            SET DescrStatus = CONCAT(xStatus, ' | ');
        else SET DescrStatus = CONCAT(DescrStatus, xStatus, ' | '); end if;
    end if;
END LOOP READ_LOOP;
```

I want to know the last position of the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by last position?  I don't see where you are setting the continue handler..

Comment: **What is your business requirement?** The question currently is looking to fix a broken solution to an unknown problem; we need to know the real problem to give you good advice.

Comment: I mean last position when procedures will occur by the last time inside of loop.

Comment: Still not making sense. Do you want the value of the PRIMARY KEY of the last record read by the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch last value of your cursor by following query (this should be outside the loop).

```
SELECT <column_name> INTO @last_value FROM <table_name> WHERE <where_conditions> ORDER BY <order_column> DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Then, add an IF statement after FETCH as follows:

```
IF xStatus = @last_value THEN
    SELECT 'Last Loop' AS Status;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the continue handler.

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
```

For more information check below link.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html